# Include JAVA SDK in appcelerator app

Tags: java, sdk, appcelerator

How can I include a JAVA SDk in my titanium app? I use the last titanium sdk (6.0.4.GA).

Thanks to answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the SDK in a module, following the documentation here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Creating_a_New_Titanium_Module

There are lots of open-source modules you can look at to see how it is done:

- https://github.com/Sitata/titanium-google-analytics
- https://github.com/manumaticx/Ti.DrawerLayout
- https://github.com/railskarthi/AudioRecorder
- https://github.com/jpriebe/ti.dfp

(some of these are cross-platform, so they have ios and android code)